Segmentation fault(core dumped) in C
Есть две струкртуры A и B. В структуре B экземпляр структуры A и указатель на неё. Пытаюсь присвоить значение полю 'a' в структуре A двум способами. C первым все ок, а вот второй почему то ошибку выдает. Не понимаю, что не так.
struct A{int a; double x;};
struct B{A a; A *pa;}x[2];

x[0].a.a = 15;
x[1].pa->a = 14;

cout << x[0].a.a;
cout << x[1].pa->a; 


Объединять  в одном операторе описание структуры с объявлением массива нельзя. После struct B { ... } поставьте ; а потом объявите массив x -- struct B x[2]; (кстати, cout << ... это не Си, а С++)

Я убрал имя: struct {A a; A *pa;}x[2];

Но все равно ошибка

И даже так: struct B{A a; A *pa;};
struct B x[2];

А почему вы к cout << ставите тег c?

Ну смотрите...
struct A{int a; double x;};
struct B{A a; A *pa;}x[2];

Что в этот момент в x[1].pa? неизвестно. Какой-то мусор. Т.е. pa указывает на какое-то место в памяти, куда, скорее всего, никакого доступа нет. А вы туда запихиваете значение:
x[1].pa->a = 14;

Туда, куда нельзя - потому что неизвестно куда. Т.е. UB. Вот и все...
Я еще понимаю
x[1].pa = new A;
x[1].pa->a = 14;

Тогда вы выделили память, куда можно писать... Правда, надо потом не забыть ее освободить :)

Ааа, вот в чем дело. А ведь логично. Спасибо огромное!

Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...
